# Are "make it right" and "put it right" the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

See this sentence

Dad said to a child, "**you peel the wrappers off the crayons and got my bed dirty. What can you do to put it right?**" or "**... to make it right?**"

It seems like both "**[put it right](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_right)**" and "**[make it right](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_right)**" means "to correct a mistake" according to some random definitions I found on the internet.

Comment: 'You **peeled** the wrappers and got the bed dirty'. Both are OK.

Comment: Yeah, both are the same thing but I wouldn't say either to a child. I'd say: How can you fix this? put it right and make it right are both very adult sounding and also sound like major mistakes on the job or in relationships with people. Not stuff.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I don't find either phrase 'adult-sounding'.

Answer (score 1):

Either is OK and would be understood as basically the same thing.

There is a slight difference in emphasis.

The "put" form is emphasizing that the person is doing outward actions. The image is of them reaching out to tidy the bed.

The "make" form is referring to action generically. So the image is of the person standing beside the bed and doing actions to tidy it. Or possibly going to get cleaning supplies or a clean blanket or some such.

As you can see, the difference is very slight.